# Height of webpage changes after uploading to heroku server

Tags: vue.js, heroku, jhipster

I have created a application using  "jhipsterVersion": "6.4.1" and blueprint is "generator-jhipster-vuejs"  "version": "1.2.0". It works perfectly fine on the local server. Then I uploaded it in the Heroku server. The web application works fine except the height of the page changes dynamically. Bottom of every component a white box appears.

[Home Page at Heroku Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Nvm.jpg)

[Home Page at Local Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLYqR.jpg)

[Settings Page at Heroku Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2o2F.jpg)

[Settings Page at Local Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8CDi.jpg)

Comment: We're not going to go off-site and log into your application. Please don't post credentials here.

Comment: That's not the only difference between the two sets of screenshots. There are spacing changes, too. Are you sure you're looking at the same code in both instances? Do you see anything in your browser console, e.g. resources failing to load?

Comment: On local server, you were on port 9000 so probably using a dev build, have you tried running locally a prod build?

Comment: I run locally a prod build and the problem was with the prod build. Why the UI is different from dev build to prod build? Do you have any solution? @GaëlMarziou

Comment: The prod build runs optimizations and verifications that would take too long for dev. Now that you have reproduced locally it should be easier to investigate by inspecting elements style in browser dev tools.If you can reproduce it on a fresh generated project that you haven't modified, it's a bug of the blueprint and you should report it. If you have customized generated app, then it's a bug in what you have added or modified.

Answer (score 0):

After spending days I found that the problem was caused by a plugin HtmlWebpackPlugin used in webpack.prod.js in the webpack folder.

I removed this line `chunksSortMode: 'dependency'` from the webpack.prod.js and everything is working fine. Change the HtmlWebpackPlugin into this

`new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/main/webapp/index.html',
      chunks: ['vendors', 'main', 'global'],
      chunksSortMode: 'manual',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
      },
    })`

And to solve the error `Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.8.0` I used `terser-webpack-plugin` instead of `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin`